# How can you write a query for Amazon redshift database such that the where clause of the correlated query has two conditions?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

Example -

```
SELECT date, name, 
       (SELECT value
        FROM this_table
        WHERE col1= 'test1' and col2='test'
       ) AS num_sloths_bought_before
FROM source_table;
```

When I execute the query in redshift, I get this error -

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported yet;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can usually rewrite Correlated Scalar Subqueries using joins, for your query it's a Left Join:

```
SELECT date, name, dt.value AS num_sloths_bought_before
FROM source_table
LEFT JOIN
 ( SELECT val, 
      value
   FROM this_table
   WHERE col2='test'
 ) this_table
ON source_table.val= this_table.val;
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and it works. The problem I am now facing is that my where clause is referring to another table --SELECT date, name, dt.value AS num_sloths_bought_before
FROM source_table,
 ( SELECT value
   FROM this_table
   WHERE source_table.val= this_table.val and col2='test'
 ) dt;

Comment: When I execute the above query in the comments, I get the error - "[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: subquery in FROM may not refer to other relations of same query level;"

Comment: @Tisha: So it's actually correlated, I edited my answer, now it's a Left Join

Comment: Actually I had another issue with this. It wasn't able to access this_table as the correlated query I was using was something like - "....Select val from database.this_table x ...." I have posted a new question here with my original query to make it more clear - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231015/how-can-i-write-this-postgres-query-in-amazon-redshift-such-that-it-is-as-optimi